# Starting multiple animations at the same time

Tags: javafx, javafx-2, javafx-8

I'm trying to start an transition in each box of every row, with successive boxes (left to right) starting their own transitions before the previous ones finish. I looked at `SequentialTransition`, but it seems to imply that transitions are started one after another after a previous one finishes.

I'm thinking I need to use a `ParallelTransition` for each row, but how can I go about doing this?

I noticed the constructor is `ParallelTransition(Animation... children)`; is it possible to call the constructor once with all the `Animation`s, given how i'm instantiating each `Animation` separately?

```
GridPane gp;

...

for (int i=0;i<gp.getRowConstraints().size();i++) {

    Timeline tl = new Timeline();
    tl.setCycleCount(Animation.INDEFINITE);
    tl.setDelay(Duration.millis((Math.random() * 2500) + 500));

    for (int j=0;j<gp.getColumnConstraints().size();j++) {

        Tile t = new Tile();

        tl.getKeyFrames().addAll(
            new KeyFrame(Duration.ZERO, new KeyValue(t.hueMultiplier, 15)),
            new KeyFrame(Duration.millis(5000), new KeyValue(t.hueMultiplier, 1))
        );

        gp.add(t, j, i);
    }
    ...
}
```

[image: Picture of currently running program]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Animation` will not start until you call `play()` method of it. So creating them separately in different places then adding to `ParallelTransition` is valid.

```
ParallelTransition pt = new ParallelTransition();
...
for(...) {
    Timeline tl = new Timeline();
    ...
    pt.getChildren().add(tl);
}
...
pt.play();
```

Comment: Thank you! Not sure why using `getChildren()` just completely slipped my mind.